# Numpy: get 1D array from a 2D array with 1 row

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a complex function that returns a 2D array, to make it simple, let's consider the following:

```
import numpy as np

def get_array():
    a = np.array([[0, 9, 5]])
    return a
```

Is there a numpy command that allows me to retrieve the single row automatically instead of doing the following?

```
def get_array():
    a = np.array([[0, 9, 5]])
    if a.shape[0] == 1:
        return a[0]
    else:
        return a 
    return a
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `a.ravel()` or `a.flatten()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.squeeze(a)` will remove any unit sized axes from `a`.

```py
>>> np.squeeze([1, 2, 3])
array([1, 2, 3])

>>> np.squeeze([[1, 2, 3]])
array([1, 2, 3])

>>> np.squeeze([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

It might not be exactly what you want though, as also:

```py
>>> np.squeeze([[1], [2]])
array([1, 2])
```

Comment: Thank you @orlp, this is exactly what I need as in my case the 2D array is (Nx3)

Comment: @mauro If my answer solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

On top of @orlp answer, if you are conscious of performance, `ravel` seems to be faster than squeeze:

[image]